# How to remove all roles from nexus user through swagger UI

Tags: swagger-ui, nexus, nexus3

I am trying to update user in nexus through `/beta/security/users/{userId}`

```
Update an existing user.
{
  "userId": "dummy",
  "firstName": "dummy",
  "lastName": "dummy",
  "emailAddress": "dummy1@dummy.net",
  "source": "default",
  "status": "active",
  "readOnly": true,
  "roles": [
    "CC_ssc"
  ],
  "externalRoles": [
    "string"
  ]
```

I am trying to remove role `CC_ssc` through above, but it showed :

```
[
  {
    "id": "PARAMETER roles",
    "message": "may not be empty"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  That's proper validation, same as the UI.
If your use case is to have the user exist but no permissions, in NXRM that's the equivalent of having them disabled.